# launchctl doesn't start cntlm daemon

Tags: macos, homebrew, launchd, plist, services

I've installed cntlm on osx using the [homebrew formula](https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew/blob/master/Library/Formula/cntlm.rb).

Then I've copied the .plist file and started the daemon:

```
sudo cp -fv /usr/local/opt/cntlm/*.plist /Library/LaunchDaemons
sudo chown root /Library/LaunchDaemons/homebrew.mxcl.cntlm.plist
```

But after the reboot the daemon isn't running. I've tried to run it manually with

```
sudo launchctl load /Library/LaunchDaemons/homebrew.mxcl.cntlm.plist
```

but its output is

```
/Library/LaunchDaemons/homebrew.mxcl.cntlm.plist: Operation already in progress
```

I've also checked the plist file with `plutil -lint` and it is ok.

This is the source of `/Library/LaunchDaemons/homebrew.mxcl.cntlm.plist`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple Computer//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
  <dict>
    <key>Label</key>
    <string>homebrew.mxcl.cntlm</string>
    <key>ProgramArguments</key>
    <array>
        <string>/usr/local/opt/cntlm/bin/cntlm</string>
    </array>
    <key>KeepAlive</key>
    <false/>
    <key>RunAtLoad</key>
    <true/>
    <key>StandardOutPath</key>
    <string>/var/null</string>
    <key>StandardErrorPath</key>
    <string>/var/null</string>
  </dict>
</plist>
```

Do you know why this happen and how to run it correctly as a daemon?

Comment: Please can you check `system.log` using Console.app for messages. `launchd` is typically good at logging useful errors and warnings about why a job is not running. Do you see the job being logged as started?

Comment: No, there isn't any start log. But if I try to start it manually it says: "Operation already in progress". I've also checked with `ps aux` if cntlm is running, but no process exists. See also https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew/issues/44741

Comment: I would change stdout and err to files and see if there is anything in them

Comment: Try put this into `~/Library/LaunchAgents` and change Output and error to `~/Library/Logs/a_log_file_appropriate` so you can get some information rather than null.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm posting this as a separate answer since I did not have to fiddle with any `plist` files to make this work.
Here's how I installed and started CNTLM today:

## Install CNTLM with Homebrew

```
brew install cntlm
```

## Edit CNTLM configuration

Edit the `/usr/local/etc/cntlm.conf` file, update the following items:

- `Username`: The user name for authenticating with your NTLM proxy
- `Domain`: Set the domain (if required)
- `Password`: Your password in plain text - only required for testing, remove this later...
- `Proxy`: Your proxy host name/IP and port (can use multiple lines)
- `NoProxy`: Add any hosts that don't need to be proxied

## Update Authentication

Run the following to let CNTLM figure out which authentication means work with your proxy:

```
cntlm -M https://www.google.com
```

This will spit out info like this, copy this into your `cntlm.conf` file:

```
Auth            NTLM
PassNT          ...
PassLM          ...
```

Next, have your password encrypted:

```
cntlm -H
```

Enter your account password when asked. This command will then print something like the following (some lines are the same as from the above command) - copy this into your `cntlm.conf` file:

```
PassLM          ...
PassNT          ...
PassNTLMv2      ...    # Only for user 'xxx', domain 'yyy'
```

Remove your plain text password from the file now and comment out the `Password` line.

You will need to run `cntlm -H` again if you change your password.

## Run CNTLM as a macOS Service

Multiple options exist for this, pick the one you like best:

```
# Start CNTLM at boot time - requires `sudo`
sudo brew services start cntlm

# Start CNTLM at login time
brew services start cntlm

# Run CNTLM on demand, don't start at boot or login
brew services run cntlm

# Stop CNTLM (might have to use `sudo` if you started it with `sudo`)
(sudo) brew services stop cntlm

# List all services managed by Homebrew
brew services list
```

More info on `brew services` can be found in [the official documentation](https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew-services).

Comment: Well done with this answer. Homebrew's new services feature made this process better. I tried this way back when I answered and brew didn't provide those kind of installations for most packages.

Answer (score 2):

I went through the homebrew information and it states the following:

- Edit `/usr/local/etc/cntlm.conf` to configure Cntlm
- To have launchd start cntlm now and restart at startup:
  `sudo brew services start cntln`

If you haven't done this, that should be your first step.

Furthermore, I don't think `/Library/LaunchDaemons` is an appropriate place for the plist file. A better location in my opinion would be `~/Library/LaunchAgents` as it runs at user login. This is a personal preference to determine when and for which system users you wish the software to run. This is important to know when attempting to debug your system if something were to fail or prevent other system operations from running properly.

I also don't think that plist file is going to run to begin with. Try my location suggestion with the following plist file code below. It has proper error output for logging so you can see what is going on located at `$HOME/Library/Logs/cntlm-output.log` and `$HOME/Library/Logs/cntlm-error.log`

For more information on Launchd startup jobs, see apple's developer documentation here: [Creating Launch Daemons and Agents](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/MacOSX/Conceptual/BPSystemStartup/Chapters/CreatingLaunchdJobs.html)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple Computer//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
  <dict>
    <key>Label</key>
    <string>homebrew.mxcl.cntlm</string>
    <key>ProgramArguments</key>
    <array>
        <string>/bin/sh</string>
          <string>-c</string>
            <string>/usr/local/opt/cntlm/bin/cntlm</string>
    </array>
    <key>KeepAlive</key>
    <false/>
    <key>RunAtLoad</key>
    <true/>
        <key> StandardOutPath </key>
          <string> ~/Library/Logs/cntlm-output.log </string>
        <key> StandardErrorPath </key>
          <string> ~/Library/Logs/cntlm-error.log </string>
      </dict>
</plist>
```

Answer (score 0):

I hit this problem just now. The following got `cntlm` going for me.

```
sudo launchctl unload /Library/LaunchDaemons/homebrew.mxcl.cntlm.plist
sudo launchctl load /Library/LaunchDaemons/homebrew.mxcl.cntlm.plist
```

This is only a workaround, I'm afraid (at least for me). The problem recurs on every reboot.